# Why do division algebras always have a number of dimensions which is a power of $2$?

Tags: binary, quaternions, division-algebras, octonions, sedenions

Why do number systems always have a number of dimensions which is a power of $2$?

- Real numbers: $2^0 = 1$ dimension.
- Complex numbers: $2^1 = 2$ dimensions.
- Quaternions: $2^2 = 4$ dimensions.
- Octonions: $2^3 = 8$ dimensions.
- Sedenions: $2^4 = 16$ dimensions.

Comment: "The sedenions have a multiplicative identity element e0 and multiplicative inverses but they are not a division algebra because they have zero divisors. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion

Comment: The original statement of this fact is from Hopf, Heinz. "Ein topologischer Beitrag zur reellen Algebra." *Commentarii mathematici Helvetici* **13** (1940/41): 219-239. See Satz IV: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002053225&physid=PHYS_0225 or http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002053225&physid=phys226

Comment: recommend http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-67

Comment: The sedenions are not a division algebra. Also, it may help to distinguish division algebras from composition algebras (*normed* division algebras). Division algebras (over $\Bbb R$) are more plentiful (although still restricted to the same dimensions 1,2,4,8) and considerably harder to prove things about than composition algebras.

Comment: The short answer is that a division algebra structure (even without a norm) induces a trivialization of the sphere $S^{n-1}$, and considering the multiplication as a map $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{RP}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$ proves that $n$ must be a power of $2$. With even more machinery, one can show that $n$ must be $1, 2, 4$, or $8$. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a more elementary proof of that fact (at least, in full generality).

Answer (score 12):

They don't. Here is a 9-dimensional associative non-commutative division algebra (over $\Bbb{Q}$):
$$
D=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1&\sigma(x_2)&\sigma^2(x_3)\\
2x_3&\sigma(x_1)&\sigma^2(x_2)\\
2x_2&2\sigma(x_3)&\sigma^2(x_1)
\end{array}\right)\bigg\vert\ x_1,x_2,x_3\in E\right\},
$$
where $E=\Bbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/7)$ and $\sigma$ is the automorphism defined by $\sigma(\cos2\pi/7)=\cos4\pi/7$.

Only over the reals are we so constrained. Topology makes a huge difference. Or, more precisely, the fact that odd degree polynomials with real coefficients always have a real zero.

Answer (score 6):

The particular family of algebras you are talking about has dimension over $\Bbb R$ a power of $2$ by construction: the [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) to be precise.